# OnDraw() animations only run when the item is moving

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview, ondraw

I want to add animations to the itemView, however they only run if the item is currently moving. For example the item starts to fadeOut until the alpha is 0, but if the item stops moving, the animation pauses and the item only fades out halfway. After that, the item needs to start moving again for the animation to complete.

I know `onDraw` typically only gets called when something changes, but I guess the OS doesn't realize the style of the View is changed as well, so it doesn't call it.

I tried adding `invalidate()` at the end so I can force an update but it doesn't do anything.

How can I fix this?

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        if (optionsState == OptionState.UPVOTE) {
            drawUpvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, dX);
        } else if (optionsState == OptionState.DOWNVOTE) {
            if (!isRightSwipeMaxed(dX)) drawDownvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, dX);
            else drawDownvoteOption(c, viewHolder.itemView, MAX_RIGHT_SWIPE_DX);
        }

        setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    if (dX == 0) {
        //This only works if the item is moving
        viewHolder.itemView.animate().alpha(1f);
        optionsState = OptionState.NONE;
    }

    if (!isRightSwipeMaxed(dX)) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setTranslationX(dX);
    } else {
        viewHolder.itemView.setTranslationX(MAX_RIGHT_SWIPE_DX);
        //This only works if the item is moving
        viewHolder.itemView.animate().alpha(0);
    }

    //Doesn't do anything
    viewHolder.itemView.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, invalidate() on the itemView did nothing.
You have to do the invalidate() on the parent recyclerView for that to work :

```
viewHolder.animatedRecyclerView.invalidate()
```